# How to implement .png pics in a JFrame?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, awt

Hi I want to make a window, a GUI, and put an image in it.

I watched a YT tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap20Qw77TzY) and copied everything similar but the Window I make has no image at all. I tried different file types like .jpg and different window sizes, matching the picture size but it doesn't help.

That's my code, I get no real errors, except a warning of:

```
The serializable class main does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long,line 8

This method has a constructor,line 25
```

### Code

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.*;

public class main extends JFrame {
/**
 * author jan
 */
public main(String title){
    super (title);
    
} 
  
public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    super.paint(gr);
    
    
    gr.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Koppenhagen\\Pictures\\Herz.png"), 0, 0, this);           
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    main window = new main("Mein Test!");
    
    window.setSize(160,160);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: You've declared `main` twice. Also, why make a class named `main` a child of `JFrame`? Just make a new project and use a JFrame as an object. Your code is not Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: @Dimitris Sfounis Oh yeah thanks, i know that im not programming object oriented, but i gotta understand this whole thing before i think about that^^
do you have any tips to solve my actual problem though?^^

Comment: Have you tried ImageIcon ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `ImageIO.read` over `Toolkit.getImage`, it will throw a `IOException` of the image can't be load for some reason
2. Check the location of the image. Your example is looking for a file in `Koppenhagen\\Pictures`, relative to the execution context of the program. You could use `File#exists` to check if the file actually exists where you think it is
3. Don't load resources within the any `paint` method, loading images can take time and painting should run as fast as possible
4. I'd discourage you from overriding paint of top level containers like `JFrame`. A `JFrame` contains a `JRootPane`, which contains, amongst other things, a `contentPane` all of which can be painted independently of its parent container. Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method instead, then add this to an instance of `JFrame`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i`ll try to follow your tips as soon as i understood´them ^^.

Comment: If we knew the relationship between the location of the image and your code, that would help

Comment: THANKS A LOT! 
I tried file.exists and figuered he couldnt find it so i put it in another folder and used the full path in my code and know its finally working ^^
thanks for your help!!!!! <3 (costed me 2 hours, the beauty of programming lol XD)

Comment: if ypu could specify or explain me your fourth answer id be helped a lot:)

Comment: Note: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: @tankman175 `JFrame` is a container for other components, we you override `paint` of `JFrame`, you are painting to the surface of the frame, technically painting over all the child components, but, because of the way painting works in Swing, child components can be painted independently of their parent container, meaning that it's possible to partially or complete wipe out anything you've painting using the `paint` method.

Comment: @tankman175 See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Swing application that draws an image.

[image]

You have to put the image in the same directory as the Java code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawImage implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new ImagePanel(getImage()));
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image getImage() {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "StockMarket.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawImage());
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2668799915861031723L;

        private Image image;

        public ImagePanel(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image
                    .getHeight(null)));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }

}
```